# AspNet Core 3 HttpClientFactory: TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, dotnet-httpclient, azure-aks

I'm using an aspnet core 3 reverse proxy in Azure Kubernetes Service, loosely based on [ProxyKit](https://github.com/damianh/ProxyKit), which used to work just fine in a previous cluster. On the new cluster (the only difference I can see is that the old one used kubenet, the new one an azure virtual network) I constantly get `TaskCanceledException`s on `HttpClient.SendAsync` when an upstream request takes more than a few seconds.

This is the relevant method that throws the exception:

```
return await _httpClient.SendAsync(
                    UpstreamRequest,
                    HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead,
                    HttpContext.RequestAborted)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The `HttpClient` is provided by `HttpClientFactory` using the typed `AddHttpClient` middleware.

Things i've tried so far:

- explicitly set a 30 seconds timeout for the `HttpClient`
- passing no `CancelationToken` to the `SendAsync` method
- implement custom timeout handling as suggested in [this article](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/)

This is how the `HttpClientFactory` was configured before:

```
var httpClientBuilder = services
                .AddHttpClient<ProxyKitClient>()
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp => new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                        UseCookies = false
                    });
```

And this is the configuration right now:

```
var httpClientBuilder = services
                .AddHttpClient<ProxyKitClient>(o => o.Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan)
                .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(sp => new TimeoutHandler
                {
                    InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        AllowAutoRedirect = false,
                        UseCookies = false
                    }
                });
```

The behavior did not change whatsoever.

How can i make sure that `HttpClient` waits for the upstream request to finish? Kestrel and HttpClient default timeouts are way higher than the requests that are aborted right now.

As a side note, when i revert to aspnet core 2.2, the behavior is exactly the same.

Comment: Task cancellation for something like `SendAsync` is going to occur when the *client* closes the connection. As such, I think you're looking the wrong place. You need to figure out why the clients are closing the connection prematurely.

Comment: Makes sense, and you are totally right. Was pulling my remaining hair out the whole day and the culprit is Azure Application Gateway with a request timeout of 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I commented:

> Task cancellation for something like SendAsync is going to occur when the client closes the connection. As such, I think you're looking the wrong place. You need to figure out why the clients are closing the connection prematurely.

As a result, the OP was able to determine that this issue lied with Azure Application Gateway:

> Makes sense, and you are totally right. Was pulling my remaining hair out the whole day and the culprit is Azure Application Gateway with a request timeout of 1 second.